# Deep copy and assignment overload and std::swap

Tags: c++11, templates, swap, unique-ptr, deep-copy

Actually I have 2 separate problems right now, so Ill divide this question into 2 parts. First one is about deep copy and assigment operator overload

First, my class header

```
template <class T>
class MyVector{    
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> p_array;
    int p_size; 
    int p_capacity; 
public: 
    MyVector();
    MyVector(const MyVector&);
    MyVector& operator= (const MyVector&);
}
```

And here are my copy constructor and assignment operator overload function

```
template <class T>
MyVector<T>::MyVector(const MyVector &source) {
    p_capacity = source.p_capacity;
    p_size = source.p_size;
    p_array = std::make_shared<T[]>(p_capacity);
    for(int i = 0; i < p_capacity; i++) {
        p_array[i] = source.p_array[i];
    }
}

template <class T>
MyVector& MyVector<T>::operator=(const MyVector &source) {
    if(this == &source) return *this;

    p_capacity = source.m_capacity;
    p_size = source.m_size;

    p_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(p_capacity);
    for(int i = 0; i < p_capacity; i++) {
        p_array[i] = source.p_array[i];
    }
}
```

In main

```
int main() {
MyVector<int> vecA;
//adding elements to vecA
MyVector<int> vecB(vecA);
}
```

Unfortunatelly what I got is

> g++ -std=gnu++14 -static-libstdc++ -g3 -Icode/include -c
>   code/source/my_vector.cpp -o obj/my_vector.o
>   code/source/my_vector.cpp:20:1: error: invalid use of template-name
>   ‘MyVector’ without an argument list  MyVector&
>   MyVector::operator=(const MyVector &source) {  ^ Makefile:29:
>   recipe for target 'obj/my_vector.o' failed make: *** [obj/my_vector.o]
>   Error 1

**Part 2**

In same class I got extendArray() function that if called, extend array capacity by 2 and copy all elements from old array to new. I tried using for loop to iterate through all elements and it works just fine, but I wanted to use std::swap instead and then I came into some strange trouble.

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::extendArray() {
    p_capacity *= 2;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> temp_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(p_capacity/2);
    std::swap(p_array, temp_array);
    p_array.reset();
    p_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(p_capacity);
    std::swap(temp_array, p_array);
}
```

in main I just do this

```
int main(){
        MyVector<int> test;
        test.pushBack(5);
        test.pushBack(10);
        test.pushBack(15);
        test.pushBack(20);
        test.pushBack(25);     

        for(int i = 0; i < test.getCapacity(); i++) {
            cout << test[i] << ", ";
        }  
    }
```

I expect to see following output (once 4th element is added, extendArray() function is called and it extends capacity from 4 to 8)
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 0, 0, 0 
And I got it when I use my old extendArray() func based on for loops, but if I use one with std::swap I get 
5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 0, 1041, 0 
I have no idea where this 1041 comes from. What's more, valgrind shows 9 erros on 4 contexts like that:

> ==5967== Invalid write of size 4 
>   ==5967==    at 0x403000: MyVector::pushBack(int const&) 
> (my_vector.cpp:17)
>   ==5967==    by 0x402CE7: main (main.cpp:11)
>   ==5967==  Address 0x542bc88 is 0 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd
>   ==5967==    at 0x4C2DB8F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
>   ==5967==    by 0x404707: operator new(unsigned long) (in /home/maciek/Programming/MyVector/MyVector)
>   ==5967==    by 0x403968: operator new[](unsigned long) (in /home/maciek/Programming/MyVector/MyVector)
>   ==5967==    by 0x40314B: std::_MakeUniq::__array std::make_unique(unsigned long) (in
>   /home/maciek/Programming/MyVector/MyVector)
>   ==5967==    by 0x402F3C: MyVector::MyVector() (my_vector.cpp:6)
>   ==5967==    by 0x402C99: main (main.cpp:8)
>   ==5967==

Comment: About part 1: you are trying to assign shared_ptr to unique_ptr in copy constructor.

Comment: Yeah right, it should be make_unique in copy constructor too. Still, same error like before. invalid use of template-name ‘MyVector’ without an argument list.

Comment: In assignment operator implementation you should specify return type as MyVector<T> instead of MyVector.

Comment: Yeah, just came up with that too. Part 1 is allright then, still have no idea how to move with part 2.

Comment: `extendArray` makes no sense at all. It's an elaborate no-op: `p_array` ends up holding the exact same pointer it started with (well, not quite a no-op: `p_capacity` now holds a value that doesn't match the actual capacity). I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to achieve with it, but whatever it is, the function ain't doing that.

Comment: `MyVector` doesn't have a method named `pushBack` - at least, not the version on it you've shown.

Answer (score 0):

Point was to copy all elements from_array into temporary array, assign new, bigger size (capacity) to m_array and then copy elements from temporary array back to m_array. I found out solution for that with following code:

```
template <class T>
void MyVector<T>::extendArray() {
    m_capacity *= 2;
    std::unique_ptr<T[]> temp_array = std::move(m_array);
    m_array = std::make_unique<T[]>(m_capacity);
    std::copy(temp_array.get(), temp_array.get() + m_capacity/2, m_array.get());        
}
```

Works just fine. pushBack() method wasn't show in code above as it had nothing to do with my problem, it just checks if there is enough space for new element (if not, extendArray() is called) and adds this element at the end of array.